# Validation bootstrap 4 with ajax sometimes not passing the data or not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, bootstrap-4

I tried to validate my form before executing ajax but i ran into some problem, when i tried to validate the data like empty the field the validation is working but sometimes when i submit the data then the ajax is executing the data is not passed and just returned empty string. I dont know why but sometimes its also working. Can you help me check my code ?

ps. i have a video for better understanding the problem, link : https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/video/4998964?key=21785443835131387bfeb191bad975b9

```
//ajax update product
        $('#btn_update').on('click', function() {
            var id = $('#idd').val();
            var product_name = $('#product_name_edit').val();
            var product_price = $('#product_price_edit').val();
            
            $('#edit_product_form').submit(function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                if ($('#edit_product_form')[0].checkValidity() === false) {
                    event.stopPropagation();
                } else {
                    $("#btn_update").attr("disabled", true).html('Loading ...');
                    $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "<?php echo base_url('admin/edit_product') ?>",
                    dataType: "JSON",
                    data: {
                        id: id,
                        product_name: product_name,
                        product_price: product_price,
                    },
                    success: function(data) {
                        $("#btn_update").attr("disabled", false).html('Submit');
                        $('[name="product_name_edit"]').val("");
                        $('[name="product_price_edit"]').val("");
                        $('[name="idd"]').val("");
                        $('#ModaleditProduct').modal('hide');
                            Swal.fire({
                                icon: 'success',
                                title: 'Data Berhasil di update',
                                showConfirmButton: false,
                                timer: 1500
                            })
                            window.setTimeout(function() {
                                location.reload();
                            }, 2000);
                        }
                    });
                    return false;
                }
                $('#edit_product_form').addClass('was-validated');
            });
        });
```

Comment: Seems like issue at php end.  My guess is that the price goes beyond your database column range and that is why 0 is updated instead of the price that you are sending.

Comment: i dont think its like that, because i tried change it to varchar with 255 but sometimes its still like that